# What does it mean for an operator to be "bounded on $L^p$"?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I am reading J. Duoandikoetxea's Fourier Analysis and on a few occasions have encountered the description of an operator $T$ being "bounded on $L^p$". Such an example of this terminology can be found at the top of page 46 where the strong maximal function $M_s$ is described by the quote:

> Then $M_s$ is bounded on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $p>1$.

I had implicitly assumed that this means the operator is bounded as an operator from $L^p$ to $L^p$ (meaning there exists $C>0$ such that $\lVert Tf\rVert_p\leq C\lVert f\rVert_p$), but I am questioning this now.

Comment: I don't see why it should mean anything else. Could you explain why you think it might mean something else in this context?

Comment: An operator might be defined $T\colon L^p\to L^q$ for all $p,q\in (1,\infty)$. I though saying $T$ is bounded on $L^p$ might mean that there exists $q\in(1,\infty)$ such that $T$ is bounded from $L^p$ to $L^q$. Or possibly that $T$ is bounded from $L^q$ to $L^p$. But I think you're right. I was just looking for reassurance really, and I couldn't find anywhere specifying exactly what was meant by this.